# AVD Manager - Can't run multiple emulators any more

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I know that the AVD Manager can run multiple emulators but with the new version in the last couple of days it stopped working. It stopped doing that thing where it launches 4 command prompt windows and it just has a loading bar but now I can't run more than 1 at once. When I click start, the load bar completes but no emulator loads, no visible changes.

The only errors in the logcat in Eclipse are:

```
07-04 10:12:18.563: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
    Address family not supported by protocol
```

No idea if this is relevant.

EDITED
I also seem to be getting this issue when starting the emulator as well sometimes:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Android_2_2_480x854'
WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\avd\Android_2_2_480x854.avd/sdcard.img
ko:Snapshot storage already in use: C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\avd\Android_2_2_480x854.avd/snapshots.img
```

This is an app created by another development team and we are just a testing team so I'm not in a position to change anything (just have the apk to test).

Things tried so far:

- Restarting ADB
- Looking up errors on Google
- Restart ADB manager /
  Eclipse

Comment: Ok I just assumed this was for Android development. If stack sites have nothing aggainst duplicates I'll move it.

Comment: Just to note, while Android development is off-topic on Android Enthusiasts we do accept "use" questions about the emulator.  This would seem to fall into that category, so I don't think it needed to be migrated.  However you are more likely to get an answer here on SO, I think, so it was probably a good thing :).  Feel free to ask any end-user questions over on Android.  CC @eldarerathis

Comment: Ok thanks for moving it across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, not working for me either since the update. It's been reported to [Google-issues](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34221) subscribe/vote to the issue so they fix it soon.

Meanwhile, a good alternative is to set a Virtual Box running the x86 Android version. It's also quite faster than the ARM emulator, though a bit tricky to setup the network and not as automatic as creating and starting emulators from Eclipse.

Comment: That issue was a duplicate and this is the new link for the issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33936